# get error when getting beta version with fastlane

Tags: react-native-ios, fastlane

When I release beta with fastlane in React native project build_app, I have this problem.

```
platform :ios do
  desc "Push a new beta build to TestFlight"
  lane :beta do
    increment_build_number(xcodeproj: "TestApp.xcodeproj")
    build_app(
      workspace: "TestApp.xcworkspace",
       scheme: "TestApp",
       include_bitcode: true)
  end
end

[14:13:21]: Error packaging up the application

------+------------------------+-------------+
|              fastlane summary               |
+------+------------------------+-------------+
| Step | Action                 | Time (in s) |
+------+------------------------+-------------+
| 1    | default_platform       | 0           |
| 2    | increment_build_number | 1           |
|    | build_app              | 366         |
+------+------------------------+-------------+

[14:13:21]: fastlane finished with errors

[!] Error packaging up the application
```

Could someone help me with this one.

Comment: Is this issue resolved ? If not can you try changing, `workspace` value in `build_app` to a relative path of the file in your `iOS` folder ?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I added a new distribution certificate which was in my keychain in first place. I removed the distribution certificate and it worked. It may not be the solution but can check